# Coldfusion Query Checkbox

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion

I need help in populating the results from the drop down selection which is dynamic. So if someone chooses school from the dropdown they will see list of schools, mostly 40 and then when the click on the school and "apply dates" field it will give them an option for adding dates. So if "apply dates" is checked only then they can enter dates. Below are my questions

1. How do you query out the results when someone clicks a particular school? Lets say field names are how_many_classrooms, projectors, etc
2. How do I use the check box to grey out and un-grey out the dates fields below and then use it in the query if dates are present?

Kinda noob in CF. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<!---javascript for keeping selected value (not working)--->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showSelection(theList) {
            var selectedValue = theList.options[theList.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById('contentDiv').innerHTML = selectedValue;
        }
    </script>


                <cfif isDefined('form.one')>
                    <cfset myschool = form.one>
                </cfif>

    <!--- if school has been selected, save (not working) --->
            <cfparam name="myschool" default="">
            <cfif isDefined('form.one')>
            <cfset myschool = form.one>
            </cfif>


            <!---cfform --->
            <cfform method="POST" action="#cgi.script_name#" preserveData="true">
            <select name="one" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option>Select Type</option>
                    <option value="school"> School</option>
                    <option value="EID">EID</option>
                    <option value="principal">Principal Investor</option>
                    <option value="books">Sponsor Booksard</option>
                </select>
            </cfform>
            <cfif structkeyexists(form, "one" ) and form.one neq "">



                <!---All the queries for dynamic drop down --->     


<cfswitch expression="#form.one#">
<cfcase value="school">
        <cfquery name="schoollist" datasource="Employees" dbtype="ODBC">
            select school 
            from schools_view order by school
        </cfquery>

        <select name="schoollist" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <cfoutput query="schoollist">
                <option value="#schoollist.school#" <cfif isDefined('form.one')><cfif form.one eq "#schoollist.school#">selected</cfif></cfif>>#schoollist.school#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </select>
       </cfcase>



    <cfcase value="EID">
        <cfquery name="EIDlist" datasource="Employees" dbtype="ODBC">
            select EID, booksardname 
            from EID_Employees 
            order by EID
        </cfquery>

        <select name="EIDlist" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <cfoutput query="EIDlist">

                <option value="#EIDlist.EID#">#EIDlist.EID# #EIDlist.booksardname#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </select>
    </cfcase>


    <cfcase value="principal">
        <cfquery name="principallist" datasource="Employees" dbtype="ODBC">
            select employee_number, selectName from Employee_View
            order by selectname
        </cfquery>

        <select name="principalList" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <cfoutput query="principalList">
                <option value="#principalList.selectname#">#principallist.selectName#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </select>
    </cfcase>

    <cfcase value="books">
        <cfquery name="books" datasource="Employees" dbtype="ODBC">
            select distinct(customer_number), name 
            from sponsor_view
            order by name
        </cfquery>

        <select name="books" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <cfoutput query="books">
                <option value="#books.name#">#books.name#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </select>
    </cfcase>
</cfswitch>
<cfelse>

</cfif>


    <tr><td>
        <cfform method="POST" action="#cgi.script_name#">
        <cfinput type="Checkbox" name="ControlName" value="Yes|No" onclick ="return true;">Check if limit by dates
        <tr><td><strong>Start of Period (mm/dd/yyyy):</strong><cfinput name="reportstart" type="text" maxlength="10" required="yes"  validate="regular_expression" pattern="[0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{4}$" message="Date should be in the form mm/dd/yyyy with leading zeros in month and day"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>End of Period(mm/dd/yyyy):</strong><cfinput name="reportend" type="text" maxlength="10" required="yes" validate="regular_expression" pattern="[0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{4}$" message="Date should be in the form mm/dd/yyyy with leading zeros in month and day"  ></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Continue"></tr>
    </cfform>






    <tr><td>If not checked, show a drop down or radio list to select desired sort order: <li>No special sorting, will display items in report in the order in which they have been entered
<li>Sort by Report Number, will display items in reportsorted using the Report Number
<li>Sort by Report Due Date, will display items in report sorted by due date from earliest date to latest date
</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Button to continue. </td></tr>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bind attribute of cfselect and cfinput make this task very simple.  The documentation on those two tags show you the detail.  Be careful about submitting forms with the onchange event of a select.  It's keyboard unfreindly.

Comment: As a general tip: Please condense code samples to the *absolutely necessary minimum*. It's a courtesy towards anyone who might read your question to spare them any details that are irrelevant to your problem. Posting 150 lines of (badly indented) code will scare away people.

Comment: Don't use `cfselect` or `cfinput`. Learn how to do this using 'raw' HTML & JS. You will thank me later. The CF UI stuff is limited and usually is NOT the most up to date version of the libraries used.